# Flask / Python - How can I figure to function if some checkboxes in HTML are checked?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am making a webscraper in Python/Flask. And I want to attribute some check boxes for users to can choose between several options.

Depending on these options, this app will show them their chosen options. My HTML code:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="css">r/css</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="golang">r/golang</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="flutter">r/flutter</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="rust">r/rust</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="django">r/django</div>
<input type="submit" value="Click">
```

And my python code is:

```
for option in options:
   if request.args.get(option) == "on":
      db = {option: []}
      data_list = get_list(option)
      db[option].append(data_list)
```

Through that for loop, I want to separate options as option. After that, I want use if conditional state to scrape data for each option.
Is there any way to extract data just for chosen options?

I tried with that if conditional state to try but it wasn't working.

Comment: Where do you derive ```options```? Include the code for it.

Comment: I want to those checkbox contents (golang, flutter, rust, etc) as options to derive

Comment: Is it possible that I put same name for those check box as options??